# real-time access to raw frames from the camera in Windows Phone 7

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

Can anyone help how to access the real-time raw frames from the camera in windows phone ?
I searched but did not got any articles on this.
I am new to Windows Phone so any help would be great.

Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 1):

I've had success using the GetPreviewBufferY method on the photocamera before. Something like:

```
byte[] buffer;
_photoCamera.GetPreviewBufferY(buffer)
```